# Redirect subfolder without wildcard to main URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Need to redirect as follows:

https://example.com/m/
to
https://example.com

but not

https://example.com/m/(.*)

Tried like this:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^m/$ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Currently doing the redirect using header('Location: https://example.com');

But good to know why the htaccess redirect not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think now working like this:

`RewriteRule ^m\/$ "https\:\/\/londonreal\.tv\/" [R=301,L]`

So basically had to escape!